# # dd + lz4 compression and de compression

Tags: backup, dd, restore, lz4

I have a CentOS server and I have take a backup of the server using following command (dd + lz4).

```
# dd if=/dev/sda bs=100M | pv -ptera -s500G | lz4 > Lenovo-Win8-sda.dd.lz4
```

It's working and now I want to restore the backup. But I don't know how to do it with lz4 and dd commands?

Answer (score 2):

simply the other way round

```
unlz4 < Lenovo-Win8-sda.dd.lz4 | dd bs=100M of=/dev/sda
```

please note that

- I drop `pv` command (is that pipe view ?)
- if /dev/sda is hosting your running OS, you may not have a coherent backup. (as your file is named win8 I guess it might be OK)
- restoring windows might need to set up boot device as well

Comment: How could I set up boot device?